# Caching REST method

Tags: java, angularjs, rest

I'm trying to cache REST method but server always returns 200 and response doesn't include Cache-Control header. Server should return 304 when cache works properly.

REST method

```
@GET
    @Path("/{id:[0-9][0-9]*}")
    @Produces("application/json")
    public Response findById(@PathParam("id") Long id, @Context Request request) {
        TypedQuery<User> findByIdQuery = em
                .createQuery(
                        "SELECT DISTINCT u FROM Product u WHERE u.id = :entityId ORDER BY u.id",
                        User.class);
        findByIdQuery.setParameter("entityId", id);
        User entity;
        try {
            entity = findByIdQuery.getSingleResult();
        } catch (NoResultException nre) {
            entity = null;
        }
        if (entity == null) {
            return Response.status(Status.NOT_FOUND).build();
        }

        CacheControl cc= new CacheControl();
        cc.setMaxAge(86400);

        EntityTag etag= new EntityTag(Integer.toString(entity.hashCode()));
        ResponseBuilder builder=request.evaluatePreconditions(etag);

        if(builder==null)
                {
                    builder=Response.ok(entity);
                    builder.tag(etag);
                }


        builder.cacheControl(cc);

        return builder.build();
    }
```

REST CALL

```
  $scope.performSearchById = function() {

        $http({
        url: 'rest/product/' + $scope.search.id,
        method: 'GET'
        }).then(function(data){
                $scope.searchResults = [data.data];

               })

     };
```

What's the way to get this properly?

Comment: What headers are present in the response on the first hit? Is Cache-Control header present?

Comment: Cache-Control isn't apear. There aren't any additional headers- just server, date, connection type and content info.

Comment: If your entity hashcode is not overridden, you will get different hashcodes for different entity instances of the same User record. You need to compare by the object contents.

Comment: I got an idea but I don't know how solve this in my solution.

Comment: Well you will have to use elimination and decompose the problem to the concrete simple elements you can solve. 1. Try to create the most simple function imaginable to return the Cache-Control header, and make sure it makes it's way to the browser. 2. Then try to add the user retrieval logic to the function. 3. Then make sure the system gets the same etag for different instances of the same user.

Comment: After restarting my server code started working corectly. Response contains ETag and CashControl headers. I wrote code based on article below

Comment: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/jax-rs-http-caching. I expect that server will return 304 but it's returning 200(cashed) right now. It seems that the browser cashed it instead of server. Do you know what is the cause?

Comment: Does the browser send the etag back to the server on subsequent requests? Is the etag value equal to the hash of the object you receive from the DB?

Answer (score 0):

An older example of mine.
The request should contain the `eTag` in the `If-None-Match`-header.
The `eTag` calculated from a cached value serverside will be matched with the value in the `If-None-Match`-header in the requests `evaluatePreconditions`.
If both are equal a 304 will be in the resulting builder.
If no header is present or does not match, return the resource and send the `eTag` with it.

```
@GET
@Path("{id}")
public Response personFromId(@PathParam("id") final UUID id, @Context Request request) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException {
    EntityTag eTag = null;
    final Optional<Person> person = fromCache(id);
    if (person.isPresent()) {
        eTag = eTagFromPerson(person.get());
    }

    Response response;
    ResponseBuilder responseBuilder = null;
    if (null != eTag) {
        responseBuilder = request.evaluatePreconditions(eTag);
    }
    if (null != responseBuilder) {
        response = responseBuilder.build();
    }
    else {
        response = personResponseFromId(id).tag(eTag).build();
    }

    return response;
}
```

The `eTag` could be caluclated by:

```
private EntityTag eTagFromPerson(final Person person) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException {
    return new EntityTag(DatatypeConverter.printHexBinary(MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-256")
            .digest(person.toString().getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8))));
}
```

or by `toString()`, `hashCode()`

Comment: hehe, I also spotted a bug :)